# A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access-97

I am building a C# application that reads a text file, writes the data read into an access 97 DB, it then reads the db and writes a file. I seem to be having some issues with my OLEDB connection string. Below is my code, anyone have any ideas why I am getting this exception?

The database does exist and I only open the connection before I execute the query and then I close it again.

```
               string fileName = "JobLogReport.mdb";
            string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + fileName + ";";
            OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

            string[] fileNames = openFileDialog1.FileNames;
            int lineSkips = 2;
            int fileCount = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.Length; i++) 
            {
                if (i == 0) { tbProgress.Text += "Reading Job Log File Number:" + fileCount + "\r\n"; }
                if (i == 1) { tbProgress.Text += "Reading Job Log File Number:" + (fileCount + 1) + "\r\n"; }

                tbProgress.Text += "- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \r\n";
                tbProgress.Text += "Populating Database \r\n";
                tbProgress.Text += "- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \r\n";
                fileReader = new StreamReader(fileNames[i].ToString());
                while (!fileReader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    String file = fileReader.ReadLine();
                    if (file.StartsWith("IC.PXPSG"))
                    {
                        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                        char[] delimiters = new char[] { ' ' };
                        string[] line = file.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DocsReceived (Filename, Documents) VALUES (?,?)";
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filename", line[0]);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@documents", Int32.Parse(line[1], NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                        command.Connection = cnn;
                        cnn.Open();
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cnn.Close();
```

Looking at the connection object I notice two things.

- Server Version says:'cnn.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
- Also cnn.Open() and cnn.OpenAsync() both don't change the state of the connection.

Comment: What line is throwing the exception?

Comment: command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Seems like cnn.Open(); isn't opening the connection which is causing the exception to be thrown.

Comment: No it doesn't seem to open the connection.

Comment: Are you specifying the full path to the DB or just the file name?

Comment: I have tried both, it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Hi.. Can you try Odbc stuffs in place of OleDB? Also try setting up a DSN to include the Access Db as a connection string.

Comment: Also ODBC requires a driver, I need it to work without a driver.

Comment: Have given the steps as an answer. Please try.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up a DSN using Control Panel>Administrative Tools>Setup data sources (ODBC)>System DSN>Add.

Give the Data Source name as MYDSN, then click on Select and browse to your Access DB.

See the snapshot.

[image]

after that try the code as follows:

```
string strDSN = "DSN=MYDSN";
string cmdText = "Insert into AccessTable (ColumnA,ColumnB) Values (?,?)";
using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection(strDSN))
{
    using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(cmdText, cn))
    {
        cn.Open();
        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", r["ColumnA"].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", r["ColumnB"].ToString());
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The image in the answer?

Comment: I have added a new image. Check it.

Comment: The image is still broken.

Comment: Its not broken for me brother. Anyways have hosted the image here http://s10.postimg.org/umihd50rd/odbc.png. Please have a  look.

Answer (score 0):

So after doing more investigation I have determined that the oledb driver in my connection string supports only 32bit applications. I am using a 64 bit machine and so the application properties automatically makes it a 64 bit application.

I did the following steps to resolve the issue:

1. Right Click on the Project in Solution Explorer
2. Select Properties
3. Select the Build Tab
4. Change Platform Target from 'Any CPU' to 'x86'(32Bit)
5. Re-build the application and it should work.